# Remove element from source code with CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, element

I have a "catalog" which is basically a (Divi) image gallery, where the prices are hidden for not-logged on users. The price is the image caption which is hidden on every page with CSS. However (of course) the element (price) is still in the source code which is not the intention, because it may only be seen by logged in clients.

The caption is hidden with this code:

```
.et_pb_gallery_caption {visibility:hidden;}
```

I've tried to add this javascript to completely remove the element from the source code:

```
if ( $(element).css('visibility') == 'hidden' ){
        $(element).remove();
}
```

But that doesn't do the trick. Hopefully someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't edit the source code that is sent to the browser with JavaScript. Removing an element from the DOM will have no effect on the source HTML. The prices should be removed server side before the HTML is sent to the client.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if($userLoggedIn){ ?>
   <caption>$9.99</caption>
<?php } ?>
```

as a commentor mentioned, you need to do this server side so the HTML sent over to the browser does not include your price.

Please note - i made up the name for the logged in check, you need to search for the proper variable in your wordpress install that represents different user log in and their types.

Comment: Ok, so I'm using Wordpress with the Divi Theme. Can I somehow load this into a child .php file, so that the caption is always hidden/removed when not logged in? Thank you!

Comment: correct that is the idea - you may be able to go into the template itself and find where the price element is created - wrap it with php and the proper variable representing login and you should be good - this way, when php send over the html to your browser, the price is excluded and therefore never will be able to be seen in the source code

Answer (score -1):

It is an ambiguous question without having source code snippet, btw if you are trying to remove the element whose visibility is set to hidden you can use following jquery code to remove it from the DOM as: 
`$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".et_pb_gallery_caption").remove();
});`
However, one can better comment if you show some code snippet.